# Nokogiri parse ajax-loaded content

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nokogiri

Is it possible for nokogiri to parse content loaded via ajax? If not how would I accomplish this?

Comment: This question doesn't make any sense. Nokogiri is server-side and ajax load is client-side. If you are serving the content, why not parse before you send to the client?

Comment: I probably should have been more specific: I need to get some content from a page on an external site, but the content I need is inserted into the page via an ajax call.

Answer (score 4):

Nokogiri can't see the AJAX content because it isn't a Javascript parser, and, as a result, can't interpret it and do the needed request.

What you want is something like Watir, or one of its spinoffs, depending on your OS. They will launch a browser, which *can* process the Javascript and resulting AJAX request.

Then, you can request the page's contents, and do your parsing of the DOM using Nokogiri.

The process is too specific for a generic example, but the [Watir platform page](http://watir.com/platforms/) will point you to the browsers supported. The [examples](http://watir.com/examples/) are pretty easy is to figure out, so you should be able to piece something together nicely.

Answer (score 1):

Just post your content to the server with an AJAX call. Here a normal controller action can handle the response, including parsing with Nokogiri.

If you mean, 'Can I parse the result of an AJAX call with Nokogiri?', the answer is no. Nokogiri is server-side software and the results of an AJAX call arrive at the client.