# Web Scraping in Ruby : Issues Scraping Data that comes from Database

Tags: css, ruby, web, web-scraping

I'm attempting to pull the Name, Address, Phone Number, and Email Address of resorts from the page(s)

http://www.exploreminnesota.com/places-to-stay/resorts/?keywords=&pageIndex=0&radius=0&mapTab=false&sortOrder=asc&sort=randomdaily&locationid=&startDate=false&class_id=7&lat=&lon=&city=&pageSize=20&type=reitlistings&attrFieldsOr=

I'm new to Ruby and have looked for some examples, but this seems to be too specific to find a suitable solution.

Focusing on the Email Address element. Having 'inspected element', and taken the CSS path (#category-listings > li:nth-child(1) > div > div > ul > li:nth-child(2) > a)

I have written the ruby script to attempt to pull this data:

```
require 'nokogiri'
require 'open-uri'

PAGE_URL = "http://www.exploreminnesota.com/places-to-stay/resorts/?keywords=&pageIndex=0&radius=0&mapTab=false&sortOrder=asc&sort=randomdaily&locationid=&startDate=false&class_id=7&lat=&lon=&city=&pageSize=20&type=reitlistings&attrFieldsOr="

page = Nokogiri::HTML(open(PAGE_URL))

site1 = page.css(' #category-listings  li:nth-child(1)  div  div  ul  li:nth-child(2) a')
puts site1
```

The output:

```
href="mailto:**%7B%7Br._source.database_fields.email%7D%7D"** class="button gaTracker" title="**{{r._source.database_fields.email}}**" data-tracker-type="event" data-category="Email" data-label="{{r._source.location.split('/')[1]}}" data-action="{{url | analyticsAction}}">Email
```

As you can see, where I want the email address, the title shows up as the call : **r._source.database_fields.email**

When inspecting this element that data shows as:

```
href="mailto:vacation@gull4seasons.com" class="button gaTracker" title="vacation@gull4seasons.com" data-tracker-type="event" data-category="Email" data-label="gull-four-seasons-resort" data-action="Places to Stay">Email
```

I'm not sure how to access the data as shown in the browser counsel. Any help would be appreciated, and would also help me to understand HTML / CSS, and how data gets pulled into a page in general from a database.

Thank you!

Comment: It looks like the data that you want to scrape isn't present in the page until after the initial page load, i.e., you're parsing the page with Nokogiri before it has had a chance to fetch its data. Here's a questioner with a similar problem: http://stackoverflow.com/q/4341387/3367343

Comment: 7stud. You're a real stud! People probably respect you. Also, Thanks for the insight . I believe I read the terms of posting and tried to create an informed question that would help others that are new to such an issue.   thohl -- thank you, sincerely.

Answer (score 1):

The following code will make a GET request to exploreminnesota.com for *only* the JSON data you want -- i.e., you no longer need Nokogiri. Then it will convert the response (a temporary file) into a Ruby JSON object and pretty-print the object to the terminal.

```
require "open-uri"
require "json"

url = "http://www.exploreminnesota.com/getJsonData.ashx?id=61&keywords=&pageIndex=0&radius=0&mapTab=false&sortOrder=asc&sort=randomdaily&locationid=&startDate=false&class_id=7&lat=&lon=&city=&pageSize=20&type=reitlistings&attrFieldsOr="

response_file = open(url) # Make HTTP request and save as temp file
response_json = JSON.parse(response_file.read) # Convert response to JSON

puts JSON.pretty_generate(response_json)
```

Notice `getJsonData.ashx` in the URL assigned to `url` -- this URL will retrieve JSON data rather than HTML.

I found `url` using the Chrome inspector. In the inspector, go to the Network tab, check "Disable cache," refresh the page, and filter the results for the "XHR" request type. Here you'll see the list of XHR requests and responses that the browser has made after the initial page load (I counted 6). Now filter those results for the word "city" and you should see the one network request that you care about. Click on it, then click the "Preview" tab -- now you can explore the JSON response right there in the inspector by expanding and collapsing the objects.

If you add the following line to my example above:

```
puts response_json["hits"]["hits"][0]["_source"]["database_fields"]["email"]
```

it will print the first resort's email address.